# Load audio file per each page in a E-book with a single play button in navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-audio, jquery-events

How could I load audio file when I click play button if I have audio files per each page?

My html mark up is some thing like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main">
        <div id='features'>
           //Page 1
            <div class='responsive feature'>///My page content goes here,</div>
            <div class="page-number"></div>
           //page 2 
            <div class='responsive feature'>///My page content goes here,</div>
            <div class="page-number"></div>
           //page 3
            <div class='responsive feature'>///My page content goes here,</div>
            <div class="page-number"></div>
            //page 4
            <div class='responsive feature'>///My page content goes here,</div>
            <div class="page-number"></div>
            //page 5 
------ //page 20</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the navigation bar, I have a audio button like:

```
<li><a id='play' href="#" title='play'>play</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have pagenumbers mapped already and assuming you have back and next events, then you can try like this.

```
  $(function() {
  var pageaudio =['01.mp3','02.mp3',  .....]
  pageupdatecallback = function (){
  var audio = pageaudio['currentpage'];
  //load source here to audio player
  }
  $('#back').click(pageupdatecallback);
  $('#next').click(pageupdatecallback);
  });
```

its not tested,